# Getting a specific element from a list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, spacy

In using Spacy, I have the following:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

sentence = "a quick John jumps over the lazy dog"

tag_entities = [(x, x.ent_iob_, x.ent_type_) for x in nlp(sentence)]
inputlist = tag_entities

print (inputlist)

[(a, 'O', ''), (quick, 'O', ''), (John, 'B', 'PERSON'), (jumps, 'O', ''), (over, 'O', ''), (the, 'O', ''), (lazy, 'O', ''), (dog, 'O', '')]
```

It is a list of tuples. I want to extract the person element. This is what I do:

```
for i in inputlist:
  if (i)[2] == "PERSON":
    print ((i)[0])

John
```

What would be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep all first element if second element is `PERSON` from first list use a list comprehension notation with a `if` at the end

```
filtered_taglist = [x for x,_,type in tag_entities if type == "PERSON"]
```

This corresponds to

```
filtered_taglist = []
for x,_,type in inputlist:
    if type == "PERSON":
        filtered_taglist.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can impose your `if` in the creation of that list:

```
tag_entities = [(x, x.ent_iob_, x.ent_type_) for x in nlp(sentence) if x.ent_type_ == 'PERSON']
```

Or here are directly the names:

```
names = [(x, x.ent_iob_, x.ent_type_)[0] for x in nlp(sentence) if x.ent_type_ == 'PERSON']
```

Comment: thank you! it seems we're almost there. the lines give "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Comment: The `if` statements had one equal sign, please check now.

Comment: This approach lets you have your answer directly, instead of creating a `tag_entities` and then going over it again to filter it.

Comment: thank you for the follow up. I did change it to double equal sign. (when the warning arrow pointed to the "="). Tried it again, now the warning arrow points to the "for").

Comment: @MarkK Gosh last shot - fixed my list comprehension syntax. Please check, thanks!

Comment: got there! thanks for the continued follow-up. your spirit moved many learners!